# Getting characteristic high points from DEM

Tags: qgis-3, point, dem, elevation

I use QGIS 3.14 and I have a DEM file which I'd like to use to get a point layer with most characteristic high points from that DEM. So every top of the mountain, hill, hillock, low etc should be extracted from that DEM to a point layer with an attribute "height" of that point. Can you recommend me any solution? Even source code would be great.

By "characteristic" i mean:

- the tops of mountains, hills and mounds
- lowest point at every valley, basin
- highest point at every watershed (might be hard to realise but i have also vector layer with rivers..)
- at roads intersection (same as above, might be hard but i have that vector layer.)

The second rule is that per every 1 km² it should be around 3-6 points, no more.

Comment: Have a look at r.geomorphon https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.geomorphon.html to identify landforms from the DEM. What do you mean 'most characteristic'? Is it the highest point? or the centre of the ridge line?

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for answer, i've already updated my question. There is more problems to solve but basically id like to get the lowest points at every valley and highest poinst at every hill

Comment: Did you have a look at the Point selection algorithms plugin? https://github.com/MathiasGroebe/point_selection - I guess you are looking for Topographic isolation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_isolation and Topographic prominence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence; see also: https://github.com/k127/osm-peak-dominance